# MySQL select child records where all parent records have the same child records, excluding all other child records

Tags: mysql

I need help with a tricky MySQL query.

These are the tables and data:

**Ingredients**

```
IngredientID  | Name
1             | Ketchup
```

**Products**

```
ProductID | Name                  | IngredientID
1         | Bills Amazing Ketchup | 1
2         | Marys Tasty Ketchup   | 1
```

**RedFlags**

```
ProductID | RedFlagID
1         | 1 (Gluten)
1         | 2 (Egg)
2         | 1 (Gluten)
```

A cooking ingredient can have multiple products. For example the ingredient Ketchup can have different types of ketchup to choose from at the store.

In this case, Ketchup has 2 possible products to choose from, ‘Bills Amazing Ketchup’ and ‘Marys Tasty Ketchup’.

Each product will have its own dietary red flags. For example Bills Amazing Ketchup contains Gluten and Egg, whereas Marys Tasty Ketchup only contains Gluten but NO egg.

What I want to do is, against the Ingredient show only the Red Flags that are applicable.

For example, the two products both contain Gluten and only 1 contains Egg. So Egg is NOT a red flag for the Ketchup ingredient because a product that doesn’t contain egg exists and the customer can purchase the Egg free alternative, therefore Egg must NOT show as a red flag against the ingredient.

However, since both products contain Gluten and there is no Gluten free alternative to choose from, therefore the ingredient must show Gluten as a red flag.

The Ketchup Ingredient should therefore show the following related data:

```
IngredientID | RedFlagID 
1            | 1 (Gluten)
```

This query must be fast because the database will contain a lot of products.

So Im not keen on having counts if possible, as I believe this would slow it down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(crf.RedFlagID) as cnt, crf.RedFlagID 
   FROM RedFlags as crf
   LEFT JOIN Products as p USING(ProductID)
   WHERE IngredientID = :ingId
   GROUP BY p.ProductID
   ORDER BY cnt DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Or, you can denormalize table `RedFlags` to save `IngredientID` there. For this case it will be a simple select without joining.